# Wordpress duplicating posts from single loop

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, advanced-custom-fields, get-posts, post-duplication

I've created a custom post type with ACF custom fields included. The CPT is being placed inside of a bootstrap slider. Everything seems to be working, except, the posts being rendered on the page are being multiplied.

There are only 4 different posts should be rendered on the page, but each one is rendering (and I counted them) 47 times. I echoed the post ID just be sure it was the same post. I can confirm that it is. I can't figure out why. Any insight or help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
               <div id="carouselTestimonial" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <?php 
                        $cptQuery = new WP_Query($args = [  
                            'post_type' => 'client-testimonial',
                            'post_status' => 'publish',
                            'posts_per_page' => -1
                        ]);
                        $active = 'active';

                        while ( $cptQuery->have_posts() ) : $cptQuery->the_post(); 
                            setup_postdata( $cptQuery );
                            $cptID = get_the_ID();
                            $addTestHomePage = get_field('homepage_testimonial_carousel');
                            $testComanyName = get_field('client_testimonial_company_name');
                            $testFirstName = get_field('client_testimonial_client_first_name');
                            $testLastName = get_field('client_testimonial_client_last_name');
                            $testTitle = get_field('client_testimonial_client_title');
                            $testImage = get_field('client_testimonial_client_picture');
                            if( $testImage ):
                                $testImgurl = $testImage['url'];
                                $testImgtitle = $testImage['title'];
                                $testImgalt = $testImage['alt'];
                                $testImgcaption = $testImage['caption'];
                            endif;
                            $testAltImage = get_field('client_testimonial_secondary_image');
                            $testQuote = get_field('client_testimonial_quote');

                            if ($addTestHomePage === "yes") : 

                                foreach($cptQuery as $cptPost) :
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="carousel-item <?php echo $active;?>">
                                        <?php echo $cptID; ?>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                                                <div class="imagesDiv">
                                                    <?php if ($testImage) { ?>
                                                        <img class="images" src="<?php echo $testImgurl; ?>" title="<?php echo $testImgtitle; ?>" alt="<?php echo $testImgalt; ?>">
                                                    <?php } else { ?>
                                                        <img class="images" src="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/<?php echo $testAltImage; ?>.webp" title="Stock Image of a Profile Picture" alt="This is a stock photo">
                                                    <?php } ?>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-9 col-md-3 col-sm-9">
                                                <?php if ($testQuote) : ?>
                                                    <div class="largeQuote"></div>
                                                    <div class="testimonialQuote">
                                                        <?php echo $testQuote; ?>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="byline"><?php echo $testFirstName; ?> <?php echo $testLastName; ?>, <?php echo $testTitle; ?></div><br />
                                                    <div class="byline"><?php echo $testComanyName; ?></div>
                                                <?php endif; ?>                                        
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php
                                    $active = '';
                                wp_reset_postdata();
                                endforeach;
                            endif; //homepage carousel check
                        endwhile;
                        //wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselTestimonial" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true">Prev</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselTestimonial" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true">Next</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
```

I've attached a screenshot of the posts in the CPT list:
[image: screenshot of posts in WP admin]

And a screenshot of the source code from the rendered page:
[image: source code of the page when rendered]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I've mis-interpreted what you are trying to accomplish, you added the `foreach` loop and you don't need it. Having it run while inside a `while` loop seems to be duplicating your intentions. Remove the `foreach` loop altogether, delete the first `wp_reset_postdata();`, and un-comment the 2nd one:

```
<div id="carouselTestimonial" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <?php 
        $cptQuery = new WP_Query($args = [  
            'post_type' => 'client-testimonial',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1
        ]);
        $active = 'active';

        while ( $cptQuery->have_posts() ) : $cptQuery->the_post(); 
            setup_postdata( $cptQuery );
            $cptID = get_the_ID();
            $addTestHomePage = get_field('homepage_testimonial_carousel');
            $testComanyName = get_field('client_testimonial_company_name');
            $testFirstName = get_field('client_testimonial_client_first_name');
            $testLastName = get_field('client_testimonial_client_last_name');
            $testTitle = get_field('client_testimonial_client_title');
            $testImage = get_field('client_testimonial_client_picture');
            if( $testImage ):
                $testImgurl = $testImage['url'];
                $testImgtitle = $testImage['title'];
                $testImgalt = $testImage['alt'];
                $testImgcaption = $testImage['caption'];
            endif;
            $testAltImage = get_field('client_testimonial_secondary_image');
            $testQuote = get_field('client_testimonial_quote');

            if ($addTestHomePage === "yes") : 
                ?>
                <div class="carousel-item <?php echo $active;?>">
                    <?php echo $cptID; ?>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                            <div class="imagesDiv">
                                <?php if ($testImage) { ?>
                                    <img class="images" src="<?php echo $testImgurl; ?>" title="<?php echo $testImgtitle; ?>" alt="<?php echo $testImgalt; ?>">
                                <?php } else { ?>
                                    <img class="images" src="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/<?php echo $testAltImage; ?>.webp" title="Stock Image of a Profile Picture" alt="This is a stock photo">
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-9 col-md-3 col-sm-9">
                            <?php if ($testQuote) : ?>
                                <div class="largeQuote"></div>
                                <div class="testimonialQuote">
                                    <?php echo $testQuote; ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="byline"><?php echo $testFirstName; ?> <?php echo $testLastName; ?>, <?php echo $testTitle; ?></div><br />
                                <div class="byline"><?php echo $testComanyName; ?></div>
                            <?php endif; ?>                                        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
                $active = '';
            endif; //homepage carousel check
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselTestimonial" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true">Prev</span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselTestimonial" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true">Next</span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you @rudtek. That corrected the issue. Very much appreciated.